# AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF fails with MS Visual Studio Pro 2013 after May 2014

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64, axacropdf

I'm using MS Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2) and MS .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938. I also have installed in my system (Windows 7 Home Premium - Service Pack 1) the Adobe Reader XI Version 11.0.07.

Before 3 months I have created a Windows Form Application with VS2013 and I've used the ActiveX tool "AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF". Everything was working normally.

I left this app for some time because of other obligations.

Now I've started using again my application and I get an error from VS2013 regarding the ActiveX control of AdobePDF in my app. The error I get is "**Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component**". I have re-installed three times Adobe Reader XI and I still get the same error.

Why VS cannot detect the COM component of Adobe reader?

I have the respective reference (Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0) added to my project and the tool (Adobe PDF Reader @C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroPDF.dll) added to my toolbox and when i try to add the tool again to my form I get the following error: "**Failed to create component 'AxHost'. The error message follows: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): A wrapper assembly is not registered for this type library....**". This is just a part of the error.

AcroPDF.dll was last modified on 08/05/2014. So i suppose its a new version.

Can you please give me a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK. After 3 hours of searching I've decided to start this question. But then I thought "let's check which .NET my app is using...".
And my app was using 4.5 when the new version of Acrobat Reader is using 4.5.1.

Problem solved.

You can understand that I'm a newbie, but I try to learn something every day. 

Cheers!